# Resetar senha atraves do RG Django

Tags: django

Boa noite...estou tentando fazer a 
recuperação de senha do usuario 
atraves do RG...mas ao enviar o formulário com o RG...
ocorre esse erro..alguém poderia me ajudar?

urls.py

```
app_name = 'usuarios'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('entrar/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='usuarios/login.html'), name="login"),
    path('saida/', LogoutView.as_view(), {'next_page':'core_home'}, name="logout"),
    path('cadastre-se/', views.register, name="register"),
    path('nova-senha/', views.password_reset, name="password_reset"),
    path('confirmar-nova-senha/(?P<key>\w+)/$', views.password_reset_confirm, name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('editar/', views.edit, name="edit"),
    path('editar-senha/', views.edit_password, name="password"),
]
```

form.py

```
class PasswordResetForm(forms.Form):

    nrg = forms.CharField(label='RG')

    def clean_nrg(self):
        nrg = self.cleaned_data['nrg']
        if User.objects.filter(nrg=nrg).exists():
            return nrg
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'Nenhum usuário encontrado com esse RG'
        )
```

views.py

```
def password_reset(request):
    template_name = 'usuarios/password_reset.html'
    context = {}
    form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        context['success'] = True
        return redirect('usuarios:password_reset_confirm')
    context['form'] = form
    context['key'] = generate_hash_key(request.user.username) # adicionas esta linha para adicionar ao context
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def password_reset_confirm(request, key):
    template_name = 'usuarios/password_reset_confirm.html'
    context = {}
    reset = get_object_or_404(PasswordReset, key=key)
    form = SetPasswordForm(user=reset.user, data=request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        context['success'] = True
        return redirect('usuarios:login')
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

password_reset.html

```
{% extends "alocar/login_base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block logado %}
 <div class="loginBox">
        <h2>Informe o teu RG</h2>
            <form action="{% url 'usuarios:password_reset_confirm' key %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar">
            </form>
 </div>

{% endblock logado %}
```

password_reset_confirm.html

```
{% extends "alocar/login_base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block title %}Alterar Senha | {{ block.super }}{% endblock title %}

{% block logado %}
<div class="loginBox color-text='white'">
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Confirmar">
            </form>
</div>
{% endblock logado %}
```

mensagem de erro

[image: PAGE NOT FOUND]

Comment: Tens algures no template {% url 'usuarios:password_reset_confirm' %}?

Comment: @Ernesto Casanova..boa noite...tenho sim...acrescentei o print do html no post...olhe novamente por gentileza...

Comment: Viva, o reset.key onde estás a passar para o contexto? O erro que ele indica é mesmo porque não existe o reset.key, experimenta colocar entre plicas um valor que sabes que existe no lugar do reset.key, por exemplo, vais ver que deixa de dar erro. Para resolver precisas de adicionar ao context só estás a passar o form.

Comment: @Ernesto casanova...boa noite ....me desculpa mas nao entendi nada..

Comment: Colocas {% url 'usuarios:password_reset_confirm' key %} no template, e na função password_reset_confirm(request, key): adicionas context['key'] = key. Se quiseres que coloque resposta completa, coloca o teu html em texto ao invés de imagem.

Comment: @Ernesto Casanova..boa noite...troquei a imagem pelo codigo html..conforme me orientou..obrigado pelo esforço em me ajudar

Comment: @Ernesto Casanova..boa noite...fiz as alterações que voce me sugeriu...
ocorreu um erro mais simples... PAGE NOT FOUND...refiz o post...agora coloquei todo o codigo envolvido no processo...
form, views, urls, html...de uma olhada por gentileza...muitissimo obrigado...estou correndo contra o tempo..tenho que entregar esse tcc

Comment: O problema está nesta linha, **reset = get_object_or_404(PasswordReset, key=key)**, aqui faz um get não deve encontrar a tua key, logo retorna 404. Já indiquei antes, o que fazes exatamente com o key obtido com o generate_hash_key? Da forma como coloquei pode não gerar a que tenhas armazenado, se é que está.

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova...boa noite, essa key é para apagar a senha antiga do usuario, ela vai junto com usuario da request para o form...na hora de renderizar o template para cadastrar a nova senha acontece essa erro 404...

Comment: Ok a key é para apagar...e?....a nova gerada é igual à que existe, leste bem o meu comentário anterior? A ideia era parar e pensares um pouco. Se a nova key gerada não é igual à que existe na db, o get **get_object_or_404(PasswordReset, key=key)** vai retornar um 404. Deu para entender agora?

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova....bom dia....ok...entao vou apaga-la...

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova..boa noite ...segui o teu conselho e apaguei onde vc me havia dito..agora aparece esse erro....'PasswordResetForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova..vc nao conhece nenhum exemplo mais facil de implementar isso nao?

Comment: Viva, um solução para reset de password, eu utilizo envio de um link com um token ou key via email tens aqui um exemplo https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html. Mesmo assim se não conseguires, para te ajudar, preciso de acesso ao teu código, não partilhaste o teu models.py por exemplo, o ideal é partilhares todo o código, colo a correr na minha máquina e vejo o problema.

Comment: Tens aqui source code com essa funcionalidade. https://github.com/wsvincent/django-auth-tutorial

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova...boa noite..mais uma vez agradeço muitissimo pela sua proveitosa ajuda, eu ja havia implementado recuperação pelo email, porem foi descartado, foi requisitada outra alternativa......vou compartilhar contigo o repositorio no github...https://github.com/DbaElvis/usuariogr   estava testando separado do projeto, essa parte da recuperação.....mais uma vez agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: partilhei uma atualização na minha reposta inicial, tens lá só que precisas para colocar a funcionar o reset da password.

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova...boa noite...ok agora está tudo certo...agradeço muitissimo a tua insistencia em me ajudar...obrigadissimo...

Comment: Olá viva, ainda bem ajudei. Aproveita e marca a minha resposta como útil, espero que seja útil para outra pessoa. Abraço.

Comment: @Ernesto Casanova..mais uma vez boa noite....sim com certeza, marquei como util.... tudo certinho na hora de resetar a senha.....funcionado legal......porem se na hora de confirmar a senha...eu colocar a senha no campo 2, diferente do campo 1, form desaparece, so fica o botao

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova..boa tarde...voce ja me ajudou bastante no outro post...teria como me ajudar nesse aqui tambem...... POST Impedir alteração do objeto no relaciomento  ....... tenho um TCC para apresentar quarta feira...desde ja agradecido

Comment: Viva, não percebi bem a tua questão. Queres evitar que seja editado um atributo? No models podes definir **editable=False**. Valida se é isso que precisas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boas, passo de novo o código, somente o que precisei de alterar, para poderes atualizar o teu com os problemas resolvidos. Poderás ter de alterar a ordem também a rota que junto abaixo, tive de a colocar antes o 'password_reset_confirm'.

**urls.py**

```
...
path('confirmar-nova-senha/(?P<key>\w+)', app.views.password_reset_confirm, name="password_reset_confirm"),
path('nova-senha/', app.views.password_reset, name="password_reset"),
...
```

**views.py**

```
# '''
# funcao para alterar senha na tela de login,
# com o usuario fora do sistema sem logar
# '''
def password_reset(request):
    template_name = 'usuarios/password_reset.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return redirect('password_reset_confirm', key=user.key)
    else:
        form = PasswordResetForm()
    return render(request, template_name, { 'form': form })


# '''
# funcao para resetar senha
# com o usuario fora do sistema sem logar
# '''
def password_reset_confirm(request, key):
    template_name = 'usuarios/password_reset_confirm.html'
    context = {}
    reset = PasswordReset.objects.get(key=key, confirmed=False)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SetPasswordForm(user=reset.user, data=request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            reset.confirmed = True
            reset.save()
            context['success'] = True
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        context['form'] = SetPasswordForm(user=reset.user)
        context['key'] = reset.key 
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PasswordResetForm(forms.Form):

    nrg = forms.CharField(label='RG')

    def clean_nrg(self):
        nrg = self.cleaned_data['nrg']
        if User.objects.filter(nrg=nrg).exists():
            return nrg
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'Nenhum usuário encontrado com esse RG'
        )

    def save(self):
         user = User.objects.get(nrg=self.cleaned_data['nrg'])
         key = generate_hash_key(user.username)
         reset = PasswordReset(key=key, user=user)
         reset.save()
         return reset
```

Comment: ..boa noite...fiz as alterações que voce me sugeriu...
ocorreu um erro mais simples... PAGE NOT FOUND...refiz o post...agora coloquei todo o codigo envolvido no processo...
form, views, urls, html...de uma olhada por gentileza...muitissimo obrigado...estou correndo contra o tempo..tenho que entregar esse tcc